# Regular polygons with common side

Tags: geometry

Given a segment $AB$ in the plane, draw all possible regular polygons having $AB$ as a side.

Is it true that if a line contains infinitely many vertices of those polygons, then   that line contains either $A$, or $B$, or the midpoint of $AB$?

[image]

Comment: There are only two regular polygons which both have $AB$ as a side, because each polygon must have side length $|AB|$, and polygons cannot overlap on more than one side

Comment: @clathratus But aren't there infinitely many with different number of sides?

Comment: @Neo right. I didn't think of that

Comment: what type of segment is it? is it a line segment or plane segment?

Comment: Sorry for misconception, I'm not a native English speaker, obviously. I've added a picture of what I meant (there's two polygons for each natural n>2 )

Comment: Is it the figure which is given with the question? or is it your imagination ?

Comment: I am a native English speaker, and your question seemed perfectly clear to me, even before you posted the picture.  "Middlepoint" should be "midpoint" but I knew what you meant.  My first thought is to left $A=(-1,0),B=(1,0)$ and figure out the vertices of the polygons.  I don't have time to work on it just now, though.

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Kju.png) is a picture of some of the points.

Comment: Interesting question. What is the source? Is the answer known?

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates of the $k$th vertex of a regular $n$-gon $(O,R)$    $\,$ are $\,$       $\Big(R\cos{2k\pi\over n},R\sin{2k\pi \over n}\Big)$. *(O(0,0))*

**Without loss of generality** let the $n$-gon's side be $α=2$[image: pctr]

${υ\over R}=\cos{\frac{\pi}{n}}   \quad   (1)\\ υ^2 +1^2=R^2 \quad  (2)$

$(1),(2)\Longrightarrow υ=\cot{\pi\over n} \quad $and   $\quad R={1\over \sin{\pi\over n}}$

Therefore, the coordinates of the $k$th vertex of a regular $n$-gon $(O,R)$  $\,$ are $\,$$\Big({\cos{2k\pi\over n}\over \sin{\pi\over n}},{\sin{2k\pi \over n}\over \sin{\pi\over n}}\Big)$

- So that $,$ $N_0N_{n-1}\parallel x’x $  we rotate the polygon by $\frac{\pi}{n}-\frac{\pi}{2}$ rad  around $O$    [(rotation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics))

  our new $k$th vertex has coordinates $\Big(\cos{2k\pi\over n}+\cot{\pi\over n}\sin{2k\pi\over n},\sin{2k\pi\over n}-\cot{\pi\over n}\cos{2k\pi\over n}     \Big)$

$\\$

- So that $,$ $N_0N_{n-1}\in{x’x}$, we have to add $υ=\cot{\pi\over n}$ to the y coordinates

**Finally** ,we end up with the coordinates:  $K_{n}^{k}\Big(\cos{2k\pi\over n}+\cot{\pi\over n}\sin{2k\pi\over n},\sin{2k\pi\over n}-\cot{\pi\over n}\cos{2k\pi\over n}  +\cot{\pi \over n}   \Big)$

which are equal to $K_{n}^{k}\Big(2\frac{\cos{(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{n})}\sin{k\pi\over n}}{\sin{\pi\over n}}+1,  2\frac{\sin{(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{n})}\sin{k\pi\over n}}{\sin{\pi\over n}}                   \Big)$

and also equal to
$K_{n}^{k}\Big(2\overset{k}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}(\cos{2i\pi\over n})+1,2 \overset{k}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}(\sin{2i\pi\over n})  \Big)$  $\quad$ [see identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro)

and also equal to $K_{n}^{k}\Big( \frac{\cos{(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n})}}{\sin{\pi\over n}},2\frac{\sin{(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{n})}\sin{k\pi\over n}}{\sin{\pi\over n}} \Big)$

*Which vertices does the line passing through $K_{n}^{0}$ (Point B in the original question) contain?*

The line which contains $K_{n}^{0}$ is $\quad$ $(l):y=a(x-1)$

$K_{n}^{k}\in (l):y=a(x-1)\iff  2\frac{\sin{(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{n})}\sin{k\pi\over n}}{\sin{\pi\over n}}=a\Big( 2\frac{\cos{(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{n})}\sin{k\pi\over n}}{\sin{\pi\over n}}+1-1  \Big)\iff \frac{\sin{(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{n})}\sin{k\pi\over n}}{\sin{\pi\over n}}=a\frac{\cos{(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{n})}\sin{k\pi\over n}}{\sin{\pi\over n}} \iff \sin{(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{n})}\sin{k\pi\over n}=a\cos{(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{n})}\sin{k\pi\over n}\iff \Big( \sin{k\pi\over n}=0\Big) \lor \Big(\tan{{{k+1}\over n}\pi}=a\Big)  \quad (3)  $

$\tan{{{k+1}\over n}\pi}=a\overset{a=\tan u}{\iff} {{k+1}\over n}\pi = u +z\pi,\quad z\in\mathbb{Z} \overset{u={m\over n}\pi}{\iff} m=k+1-zn, \quad \gcd{(m,n)}=1   $

Using this we find for example that the line described by: $y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}(x-1)$ contains all vertices satisfying $n=6k+6$

[image]

$\\$
We can restate the problem equivalently ,algebraically :

> $\exists ^{\infty} (n,k):   2 \overset{k}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}(\sin{2i\pi\over n})=a\Big(  2\overset{k}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}(\cos{2i\pi\over n})+1  \Big)    
>  +b ,\quad a,b\in{\mathbb{R}}\\ \Longrightarrow (b=a)\lor (b=-a)\lor (b=0) $

or

> $\exists ^{\infty} (n,k): 2\frac{\sin{(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{n})}{{\sin{k\pi \over n}}}}{\sin{\pi\over n}}=a\Big(\frac{\cos{(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n})}}{\sin{\pi\over n}} \Big)+b, ,a,b\in{\mathbb{R}} \Longrightarrow (b=a)\lor (b=-a)\lor (b=0)  $

Similar problems, arguably simpler, have been solved [[5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338183/rational-a-and-b-in-0-frac12-such-that-cosa-pi-cos2b-pi?noredirect=1&lq=1)],[[6](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633848/does-sin2-frack-pin-sin-frac-pin-have-infinitely-many-integer-s)]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If we look at the polygons with $4n$ sides ($n\ge 2$)

We come close to finding a line where all polygons have a vertex on that line, and the line goes through neither A, B nor the midpoint of AB.  It's not exact, but in mathematics appearances can be deceiving.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not right.  It is only approximately correct.  As I dig into it, the points are almost co-linear, but not quite.

Comment: Made the correction in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, too long for a comment:

This is really just an attempt to establish what we're trying to solve in terms of complex numbers, where colinearity may be easier to describe, etc. 
$
\newcommand{\i}{\mathbf{i}}$
If we rotate 90 degrees, and work in the complex plane, placing $A$ at $+\i$ and $B$ at $-\i$, and only look in the right half-plane (because...symmetry!), then the polygon centers are all on the real line. The center of polygon $n$ is at 
$$
c_n = \sec \frac{\pi}{n} + 0 \i
$$
and the $k$th point of that polygon is at 
$$
u_{n,k} = c_n + (\sec \frac{k\pi}{n} + \i \csc \frac{k\pi}{n}).
$$